# SQL Server Management Studio : execution timeout expired

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep on getting a timeout in my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I'm not running any code. All I am doing is trying to look at the tables within a database in the Object Explorer. I always get:

> Execution Timeout Expired

[image]

I've looked at some of my settings and it says lockout of 0, meaning it should be unlimited time. I'm not even running any code. Just trying to understand what's in my database by going through the Object Explorer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your work environment. But in all cases, I trust it is related to the Database but not the Studio itself.

If you are working on a server that is reached by the network by many other clients, then:

- It could be a transient network problem,
- High load of requests on the Server,
- Deadlock or other problems related to multiprocess contention.

I suggest you troubleshoot your server in idle time, and if possible you detach the databases one by one and work to see which database is resulting in the problem. For this database, you go through the Stored Procedures and Functions and try to enhance them in terms of performance.